# How to pass parameters to a partial view in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, controller, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Suppose that I have this partial view:

```
Your name is <strong>@firstName @lastName</strong>
```

which is accessible through a child only action like:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult FullName(string firstName, string lastName)
{

}
```

And I want to use this partial view inside another view with:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("FullName")
```

In other words, I want to be able to pass firstName ans lastName from view to partial view. How should I do that?

Comment: Very closely related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909134/passing-parameters-to-my-partial-view

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Use this overload ([`RenderPartialExtensions.RenderPartial` on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492962.aspx)):

```
public static void RenderPartial(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string partialViewName,
    Object model
)
```

so:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial(
    "FullName",
    new { firstName = model.FirstName, lastName = model.LastName});
}
```

Comment: Well, tried that, but I'm getting _The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments_ error. How should I implement the controller method? Should it have input parameters?

Comment: The RenderPartial method returns void, as the views render directly into the output stream, not into a string.  I edited my answer to fix this issue.

Comment: did you add the {} around the call? it needs to be @{Html.RenderPartial("FullName", new { firstName = model.FirstName, lastName = model.LastName});}    not     @Html.RenderPartial("FullName", new { firstName = model.FirstName, lastName = model.LastName});

Comment: That did the trick. But it's so messy and dirty. Why should it be wrapped inside another pair of curly braces?

Comment: So you passed parameter like this, how do you access it in partial view?

Comment: You also don't need the brackets. `@Html.Partial()` is the same as `@{Html.RenderPartial();}` but much prettier. They have the same overloads as well.

Comment: How do you access the object? `Model.firstName` and their like throw an exception that `object doesn't have a 'firstName' property`

Comment: As to whether or not you need the brackets, no you don't. However, using the brackets is *slightly* more optimal because it is written directly to the response stream.

Comment: @ashes999 you can access via ViewData... but help keep things tidy by simply creating a model specific to your usage. Use it once and some may consider it a toss up, but use it any more times than that and it's a no-brainer.

Comment: Can I add `Html.RenderPartial` as an `onclick` event for a button?

Answer (score 95):

Here is another way to do it if you want to use ViewData:

```
@Html.Partial("~/PathToYourView.cshtml", null, new ViewDataDictionary { { "VariableName", "some value" } })
```

And to retrieve the passed in values:

```
@{
    string valuePassedIn = this.ViewData.ContainsKey("VariableName") ? this.ViewData["VariableName"].ToString() : string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer did the trick without creating a model for this.

Comment: Out of all the examples, this is the only one that fully worked for me. thanks

Comment: This is what i was looking for, no model. thank you :)

Comment: Excellent answer - but with MVC 4 use Html.RenderPartial instead of Html.Partial

Comment: I had to use `new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData) {` to get it to work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43136848/1741690 so: `await Html.RenderPartialAsync("~/PathToYourView.cshtml", null, new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData) { { "VariableName", "some value" } } );`

Comment: @SharpC, It solved the error showing in viedatadictionary but i am unable to get the value in the partial view

Comment: @SharpC should be because you were using AspNetCore. ViewDataDictionary is available in System.Web.Mvc and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures with different constructors.

Answer (score 25):

You need to create a view model. Something like this should do...

```
public class FullNameViewModel
{
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }

     public FullNameViewModel() { } 

     public FullNameViewModel(string firstName, string lastName)
     {
          this.FirstName = firstName;
          this.LastName = lastName;
     }

}
```

then from your action result pass the model

```
return View("FullName", new FullNameViewModel("John", "Doe"));
```

and you will be able to access `@Model.FirstName` and `@Model.LastName` accordingly.

Answer (score 15):

make sure you add {} around Html.RenderPartial, as:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("FullName", new { firstName = model.FirstName, lastName = model.LastName});}
```

not

```
@Html.RenderPartial("FullName", new { firstName = model.FirstName, lastName = model.LastName});
```

Comment: How does the definition of your Partial View looks? What is the @model declaration? Its anonymous...

Comment: yes make sure to add `{ }`, i wasted time until i found [this](http://www.quickstepit.net/html-renderpartial-void-erro/) article

Answer (score 7):

Following is working for me on **dotnet 1.0.1**:

**./ourView.cshtml**

```
@Html.Partial(
  "_ourPartial.cshtml",
  new ViewDataDictionary(this.Vi‌​ewData) {
    {
      "hi", "hello" 
    } 
  }
);
```

**./_ourPartial.cshtml**

```
<h1>@this.ViewData["hi"]</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just:

```
@Html.Partial("PartialName", Model);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@{
            Html.RenderPartial("_partialViewName", null, new ViewDataDictionary { { "Key", "Value" } });
        }
```

in the place you want to show your partial,

```
 @{
    string valuePassedIn = this.ViewData.ContainsKey("Key") ? this.ViewData["Key"].ToString() : string.Empty;
}
```

in the partialview rendered,

To use the valuePassedIn --> @valuePassedIn

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this question, and I have a similar situation

my problem is as follows :
I have more than one variable I need to pass to the partial view I created

The solution I have created

```html
@{
await Html.RenderPartialAsync("YourPartialViewName",new { NumberOfProducts = ViewData["NumberOfProducts"], UserName = ViewData["UserName"] });
}
```

In the above code, I created an anonymous object and sent it to the view
and the following code is to explain how to retrieve the data that sent
through this object

```html
     <span>
          @Model.UserName
      </span>

     <span>
          @Model.NumberOfProducts
      </span>
```

hope this helps