# Partial Layout in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have one Partial View as follows

_MyNav.cshtml

```
<ul>
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("Link1", "Index", "Link",new { id="" }, null)
    </li>
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("Link2", "Index", " Link ",new { id="1" }, null)
    </li>
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("Link3", "Index", " Link ",new { id="2" }, null)
    </li>
</ul>
```

I included the partial view in two places in my main layout file.
@Html.Partial("_MyNav").
One of the partial views needs to have all the links the other one needs to have two links.

Is there anyway that I would be able to hide one of the links in _MyNav by passing the parameter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass parameters to a partial view in ASP.NET MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549541/how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-partial-view-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 1):

Make your partial strongly typed to a model (boolean in your case):

```
@model bool

<ul>
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("Link1", "Index", "Link",new { id="" }, null)
    </li>
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("Link2", "Index", " Link ",new { id="1" }, null)
    </li>
    @if (Model)
    {
        <li>
            @Html.ActionLink("Link3", "Index", " Link ",new { id="2" }, null)
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

and then if you want to have 3 linkks:

```
@Html.Partial("_MyNav", true)
```

and if you want to have 2 links:

```
@Html.Partial("_MyNav", false)
```

Of course if you need to pass more complex information to the partial than just a boolean value you would define a view model and then make your partial strongly typed to this view model.