# MVC Partial View Will Not Load

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I keep getting an error message along the lines of:

> ..but this dictionary requires a model item of type..

My view I'm trying to put the partial view into is:

```
@using TheNovelMachine.Models
@model TheNovelMachine.Models.Account

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<img id="homeimage" src="~/Image/front-page-book.jpg" alt="The Novel Machine" />

<div id="text" class="col-lg-12">
    <h1>Profile</h1>
    <div class="col-lg-6 no-gutter">
        <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Username)</h2>
        <h4>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FullName)</h4>
        <p>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email)</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6 pull-right text-right no-gutter">
        <img class="profilepic" src="~/Image/@(Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Username)).jpg" />
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12 no-gutter">
        <hr/>
        <h4>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Username)'s Novels</h4>
        @{
            Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/_NovelProfile.cshtml");
        }
    </div>

</div>
```

And the Partial View is:

```
@using System.Web.DynamicData
@using TheNovelMachine.Models
@model IEnumerable<TheNovelMachine.Models.Novel>


<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Genre)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Abstract)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Privacy)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AccountId)
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.Where(i => i.AccountId.ToString() == Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString())) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Abstract)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Privacy)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AccountId)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: A few things to note, first you're doing logic in a view when you call `.Where(...)`, logic in a view is typically frowned upon.  Secondly (optionally), instead of looping through the items, create a DisplayTemplate for `Novel`, then simply replace the entire loop with `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your partial view is expecting this model (you are declaring it at the top of you partial view)

```
@model IEnumerable<TheNovelMachine.Models.Novel>
```

You should pass that model in this line:

```
@{
        Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/_NovelProfile.cshtml", Model.Novels);
}
```

That should work, assuming `Model.Novels` is of this type `IEnumerable<TheNovelMachine.Models.Novel>` or it can be converted to that type.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549541/how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-partial-view-in-asp-net-mvc) you have an example with more details, but the idea is the same. If you don't pass this as a parameter, then the partial view can't be constructed (that's why you are getting that error).

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492962(v=vs.118).aspx) Documentation here for RenderPartial method.

Answer (score 1):

So even though there are other answers as to what you need to do, here is what is actually happening, so you know in the future.

```
@Html.RenderPartial("_NovelProfile");
```

would be the same code as:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("_NovelProfile", Model)
```