# How to pass in HTML to a Razor Partial View?

Tags: c#, .net, razor, razor-pages

I want to pass in HTML to my partial view, like so:

```
@Html.Partial("_MyForm", "<button id='foo'>Process Data</button>")
```

This currently works, but passing in strings is inelegant. Previously, IHTMLString allowed you to do this instead (see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549541/how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-partial-view-in-asp-net-mvc)):

```
public class HTMLViewModel
{
    public Func<object, IHtmlString> Content { get; set; }
}

@Html.Partial("_MyForm", new HTMLViewModel()
{
    Content =  
    @<button>
       <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </button>
})
```

IHTMLString no longer exists in .NET Core, can the approach still be replicated with some other feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `IHtmlContent` to maintain your current approach:

```
public Func<object, IHtmlContent> Content { get; set; }
```

And then in the partial:

```
@model HTMLViewModel
@Model.Content(null)
```

Depending on which version of .NET Core you're using you could also take advantage of some of the inline function markup changes discussed here: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore-Tooling/pull/334

Comment: is this still the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

For aspnet core razor take a look at "Templated Razor delegates" [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-8.0#templated-razor-delegates)

Your syntax should work:

```
public class HTMLViewModel
{
    public Func<dynamic, object> Content { get; set; }
}

@Html.Partial("_MyForm", new HTMLViewModel()
{
    Content =  
    @<button>
       <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </button>
})
```

More generally, you can create strongly typed templates as well:

```
Func<T, object> template = @<div>@item.Foo</div>;
```

(where T is your type).

You can then pass that function around (in to your partial view) and invoke as such:

```
@template(new T { Foo = "Bar" })
```

Notice that the parameter passed in is accessed via `@item`. (My VS adds a red squiggle for this but it can be ignored!)