# How to pass custom parameter in partial view and change label of form without using model?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Partial view is called in layout.cshtml, I am unaware of how to pass parameter

```
   @Html.RenderPartialAsync("_DatePickerPartial","passString parameter");
```

Partial view

```
<div class="Date-picker>

 <label for=" ">@string parameter here</label>

</div>
```

I want to change label when partial view is called in different pages.
Also, if I could pass multiple parameters through partial view in layout. Open to use different method like using html tag helper/tag helpers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass parameters to a partial view in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549541/how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-partial-view-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: I dont have controller for the partial view as in the link mentioned.

Comment: @pfx using data dictionary it showing that ViewDataDictionary doesnot contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Answer (score 2):

Below is a work demo, you can refer to it:

_layout:

```
           @{
                ViewData["passing string"] = "bbb";
            }
          
            <partial name="_DatePickerPartial"  view-data="ViewData" />
```

_DatePickerPartial:

```
<div class="Date-picker>

    <label for=" ">@ViewData["passing string"]</label>

</div>
```

**OR:**

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("_DatePickerPartial",
            
            new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData)
            {
            { "passString parameter", "sss" }
            })
```

_DatePickerPartial:

```
<div class="Date-picker>

    <label for=" ">@ViewData["passString parameter"]</label>

</div>
```

**The third way**:

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("_DatePickerPartial",

            new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData)
            {
            { "Property1", "Value1" } , { "Property2", "Value2" }})
```

_DatePickerPartial:

```
<div class="Date-picker>

    <label for=" ">@ViewData["Property1"]</label>
    <label for=" ">@ViewData["Property2"]</label>

</div>
```

Comment: @sumitkhatrii Please have a look at my answer.

Comment: It works, though I opted for  html tag helper. Thank man @QingGuo. The answer is on point for my quesstion.